# Passing dataItem in kendo grid in kendoGridToolbarTemplate button

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have my grid in html:

```
  <kendo-grid [data]="gridData"
    [selectable]="true">
    <kendo-grid-column field="date" title="Date">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        {{dataItem.date| date: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'}}
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    
    <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate [position]="'bottom'" let-dataItem>
        <button class="downloadButton" (click)="onClick({e: $event, dataItem: dataItem})" kendoButton>Download</button>
    </ng-template>  
  </kendo-grid>
```

And my function in my component.ts:

```
  public onClick({e, dataItem}: {e: Event, dataItem: Project;}): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    console.log(dataItem);
  }
```

But the console log shows `undefined`. Why does the `let-dataItem` work in the ng-template above in the grid column, but not when passing the dataItem to the `onClick` function?

Can I do it like this or do I need to use a SelectionEvent in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

A kendogrid cell has a `dataItem` attribute, but the grid itself hasn't. How should it have? It is a grid, it has a collection of rows (data items), not just a single `dataItem`. If you want to download the grid data, just simply export it: [how to export](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-known-limitations).

Or if you want to access the grid data in code, then set a template variable to the grid and access it's data f.e. like this: `const gridData = (<GridDataResult>this.grid.data).data;`.